# Laravel Registration

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to have a separate table for registration and separate table for authentication in the default Authentication scaffolding of  laravel?

I have checked the config/auth.php but it only allow 1 table which is "users" as default.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? because what you want does not make sense. Why do you want to 2 separate tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check the `RegisterController.php` file which is in the same folder as `LoginController.php`

check the following functions

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
```

change `'unique:users'` to `'unique:custom_table'`

Comment: sorry I can't reply with a comment because I need to show multi-line code

Answer (score 0):

please try to open the `RegisterController.php` file 
at `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`

at the very end, there is a `create` function, just override this function

for example

```
this is the default:

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

change it to something like:

```
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        TableForRegist::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it and I think it is correct, but another error ocurred. There is a part in registration where it checks the email if there is a duplicate and it points to the default table name which is "user" instead of my custom table name.